# Generate an image / thumbnail of a webpage using X/Gui-less linux

Tags: php, python, linux, image-processing

There exists numerous solutions on generating a thumbnail or an image preview of a webpage. Some of these solutions are webs-based like websnapshots, windows libraries such as PHP's imagegrabscreen (only works on windows), and KDE's wkhtml. Many more do exist.

However, I'm looking for a GUI-less solution. Something I can create an API around and link it to php or python.

I'm comfortable with python, php, C, and shell. This is a personal project, so I'm not interested in commercial applications as I'm aware of their existence.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can run a web browser or web control within [Xvfb](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xvfb), and use something like `import` to capture it.

Comment: I never thought of using Xvfb; from my understanding it runs on memory. my server only has 512 mb ram. I wonder if i'll face any performance issues. Second, do you think i'll need to set up a queue for multiple requests?

Comment: I would set up a queue for it. Xvfb is not exactly a speed demon, and having multiple instances open could get hairy fast. I wouldn't worry too much about memory though; a 32-bit 1024x768 screen only needs about 3MB.

Comment: I'll keep this question open for now, hoping other solutions popup .. meanwhile, I'll try and implement xvfb

Answer (score 1):

I'll never get back the time I wasted on wkhtml and Xvfb, along with the joy of embedding a monolithic binary from google onto my system. You can save yourself a lot of time and headache by abandoning wkhtml2whatever completely and installing phantom.js. Once I did that, I had five lines of shell code and beautiful images in no time.

I had a single problem - using ww instead of www in a url caused the process to fail without meaningful error messages. Eventually I saw the dns lookup problem, and my faith was restored.
But seriously, every other avenue of thumbnailing seemed to be out of date and/or buggy.

phantom.js = it changed my life.